# Return list from a dataframe of a value who's date matches the date from a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have a pandas dataframe `df_testing_set` which looks like this sample:

```
Index Ycurrent.   date.   bucket_id.   
 .     245    June 17, 2017.   45
 .     235    June 17, 2017.   46
 .     265    June 18, 2017.   47
 .     235    June 18, 2017.   48
 .     225    June 19, 2017.   49
 .     205    June 20, 2017.   50
 .     215    June 21, 2017.   51
 .     212    June 22, 2017.   52
 .     225    June 23, 2017.   53
 .     257    June 24, 2017.   54
 .     236    June 25, 2017.   55
 .     248    June 26, 2017.   56
 .     245    June 27, 2017.   57
 .     245    June 27, 2017.   58
```

and I have a list of 8 random dates from another dataframe that looks like this:

```
0.   June 01, 2017
1.   June 23, 2017
2.   June 13, 2017
3.   June 27, 2017
4.   June 17, 2017
5.   June 04, 2017
6.   June 09, 2017
7.   June 11, 2017
8.   June 15, 2017
```

Given the data above, how do I (for each date in the `date_list`), select all the records for that specific date (From my code it looks like there's around 144 rows per date).

With this data I've been trying to get (x,y) where `x` is the value in `bucket_id` (Goes from 1-144) and y is the value in the field `Ycurrent`. The coordinates are then used with matplotlib to plot a line graph.

My graphs don't show when I try to plot then using matplotlib. I tried to plot all the lines on the same graph, since the x-axis remains the same for all dates, but I keep getting

```
raise ValueError('Must pass DataFrame with boolean values only')

ValueError: Must pass DataFrame with boolean values only
```

Comment: Please do not pictures since it's impossible for us to replicate.

Comment: Please avoid to put images of data. It is impossible for us to reproduce your problem and help you.

Comment: Sorry, what should I do instead?

Comment: Just put a sample of data in [a form](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can copy and paste to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @FabioLamanna edited and resubmitted. I'll make a note to always do that in the future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can filter your original dataframe with `isin`:

```
df_testing_set = df_testing_set[df_testing_set['date'].isin(date_list[1])]
```

where `date_list[1]` is supposed to be the column related to the date of your second dataframe/list of dates.

If you want the first Index just subselect it:

```
df_testing_set = df_testing_set[df_testing_set['date'].isin(date_list[1])]['Index']
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: When I try that, I get a large data frame that has the records for *all* the data in the list. How do I specify it to only give me stuff for the first index? When I try, it keeps erroring out and stating that `isin` is looking for a list-like object

Comment: I do want the first index, but when I run your edit I get `KeyError: 'Index'`

Comment: Is that the name of the column you want to extract? If it is a pure pandas index try `.index` instead of `['Index']`.

Comment: Tried that, no change really. Is there no way to specify that I want all the data in the `df` which has a date of `June 27, 2017` to be put into a new `df`?

Comment: Well that was what I answered at. But there you wanted to filter all dates in the main `df` which are also in your `date_list` right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149408/discussion-between-tushariyer-and-fabio-lamanna).